# Error connecting to SDL Tridion 2011 (GA) CME

Tags: tridion

I've just configured my CME site with a new host header. The old header still works correctly, but when I use the new one I get an error "Unable to connect to the remote server". I can't see anything in the Event Viewer, any idea what this might be, or where to look for more info?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using host headers to access the CME, you need to adapt the "Tridion.WCF.RedirectTo" key in web\WebUI\WebRoot\Web.config (say that 5 times fast!)